# OpenTok No Reply From Server

Tags: php, javascript, opentok

I am trying to generate session Ids for users on a website using opentok.

I am using a tutorial from the opentok website to create the session id (https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-PHP-SDK).

The problem is that when I run the code, the website keeps on loading and no reply from the server is occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem by commenting out these lines from OpenTokSDK.php

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    $value = urlencode($value);
    $dataString .= "$key=$value&";
}
```

Comment: Hey Brute, I work for TokBox (company that makes OpenTok). I'm wondering if your solution successfully makes session ID's and tokens that work n your page. It sounds like you basically neutered the `_do_request` function and it wouldn't work. If you need further help, let me know.